# What happened to "Reopen Recent Project" action in IntelliJ 14.1?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, keymapping

I would like to bind a key shortcut to `Reopen Recent Project`.

You can find this action in IntelliJ 14.0.3 by hitting ctrl+shift+A and typing `reopen`: you will see `Reopen Recent Project`. You can also find this action under `Other` in Settings -> Keymap and set a key binding.

But in IntelliJ 14.1, this action seems to have disappeared. Of course I can use the `File` menu to choose `Reopen Project` but this is slow, and you can't bind a keyboard shortcut to this menu item in Settings -> Keymap :(

Help please!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was removed, but it will be back. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-136619

Use [Frame Switcher plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7138?pr=idea) instead.

Comment: Ok, we wait for 14.1.2 then. Thanks!